# How to bind values dynamically in v-model in vue 2

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am facing an interesting problem. I have two tables of a user. One table is users and another is information. Now when signing up, userinfo table can be blank or filled. If filled then there is no problem.

The problem, when I create a form to update/create(new record of userinfo as he didn't provide while signing up.) I try to get data from database and store in an object. Something like this

```
    data(){
      return {
          data:user[0].userinfo
        }
    },
```

and in my form I auto populate the form using v-model

```
<input type="text" v-model="data.address" />
```

Clearly you see the problem. Since this user has no records, the value of data will `null`

On the other hand if the user provide the userinfo while signing up, these issue doesn't exists as there will be data.

How can I solve this errors?

Currently what I do is create conditional forms mean two forms. One for editing for the user whose data is available and one for editing. But I have to create two forms and some extra coding. Is there any ways we escape errors and work with one form? 
Thank you/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define your `data` property first as an empty object with all of the properties required by the form and then assign that object the `userinfo`:

```
data() {
  let userData = {
    address: '',
    name: '',
    email: '',
  }

  return {
    data: Object.assign(userData, user[0].userinfo);
  }
},
```

This way, if there is no data in `user[0].userinfo` your `data` property will still have all of its needed properties defined.

Comment: Thank you. Very nice and smart approach!

Comment: can I escape null when a composite object bounded, e.g.    
data () { return { map: new Map();} }

v-model="map['name'].value",   where name is an instanceof class MyField,  I want the API automatically create an object and map['name'] = new MyField() when map['name'] is null / undefined.   in my page,  'name' itself is not static defined, but retrieve from remote resource, so that I don't know its name before program runs, and not all MyField is used by same input tags, some are used by input, some used by select tag and even table, etc.